# Can Australian government departments use ISP meta data for general analytics

Tags: internet, australia, regulations

In Australia all ISP s have to capture 2 years of all users metadata, a number of government departments can access the data with out warrant. We are told this is to track terrorists, criminals and peodophiles.

Knowing the internet usage of all people in Australia would create a data goldmine that could be used for far more than chasing criminals. Under the legislation could they use the data for general analytics

Answer (score 1):

### No

Your question states "a number of government departments can access the data with out warrant" - this is not true. [s110](http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/cth/consol_act/taaa1979410/s110.html) of the TELECOMMUNICATIONS (INTERCEPTION AND ACCESS) ACT 1979 requires a warrant before accessing data.

Further, such warrants are for specific persons so cannot access "the internet usage of all people in Australia".

This is all summarized in [s107](http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/cth/consol_act/taaa1979410/s107g.html):

> The purpose of the preservation is to prevent the communications from being destroyed before they can be accessed under certain warrants issued under this Act.
>
> Under the system, certain agencies can give a preservation notice to a carrier requiring the carrier to preserve all stored communications that the carrier holds that relate to the person or telecommunications service specified in the notice.